# PHP MySQL column total

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I need a little help fixing some code I have.

I have a query that pulls out a number of rows from a table but I need it to total the value in one of the columns 'Price'.

I have got the total calculation to work fine and output but it appears to be breaking my repeat region further down the page.  I am assuming it is something to do with the WHILE statement but I'm not entirely sure how to fix it.  Could anyone suggest a way to fix it or offer an alternative.

```
mysql_select_db($database_otters, $otters);
$query_CartDetails = "SELECT eventregistrations.*, swimmers.*, events.*, eventtypes.*, timetable.*     FROM eventregistrations LEFT JOIN swimmers ON eventregistrations.SwimmerID=swimmers.SwimmerID LEFT JOIN events ON eventregistrations.EventID=events.EventID JOIN eventtypes ON events.EventTypeID=eventtypes.EventTypeID JOIN timetable ON eventregistrations.ParentDiaryID=timetable.DiaryID WHERE eventregistrations.SessionID = '$sessionid'";
$CartDetails = mysql_query($query_CartDetails, $otters) or die(mysql_error());
$row_CartDetails = mysql_fetch_assoc($CartDetails);
$totalRows_CartDetails = mysql_num_rows($CartDetails);

$cartvalue= 0;
while ($num = mysql_fetch_assoc($CartDetails)) {
    $cartvalue += $num['Price'];
}
```

This is the code for the repeat region which works fine if I comment out the 'cartvalue' section above:

```
<?php do { ?>
<tr>
    <td><?php echo $row_CartDetails['Fixture']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row_CartDetails['EventType']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row_CartDetails['SwimmerFName']; ?> <?php echo $row_CartDetails['SwimmerSName']; ?></td>
    <td>£<?php echo $row_CartDetails['EventCost']; ?></td>
</tr>
<?php } while ($row_CartDetails = mysql_fetch_assoc($CartDetails)); ?>
```

Comment: mysql is deprecated. You should migrate to something like pdo. Just saying.

Comment: You looped through the set of `mysql_fetch_assoc($CartDetails)` already once before the "repeat region", so when you use it a second time, it has nothing to return anymore.

Comment: What do you get when it's not working fine?

Comment: It displays the first row and displays the total when it breaks the repeat region.

Answer (score 0):

Yes the issue is here

```
while ($num = mysql_fetch_assoc($CartDetails)) {
    $cartvalue += $num['Price'];
}
```

You are looping through the result set and the pointer after the white loop will be set to the end of the result set. So if you do further iteration on the same result set then you are likely to get nothing.

In this case when you need to do iteration again you will need to reset the pointer using

[**mysql_data_seek**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-data-seek.php)

So before running the 2nd loop do something as

```
mysql_data_seek($CartDetails, 0) ; // this will set the pointer to the 1st row
```

NOTE : You are using deprecated version of mysql functions, start using mysqli or pdo with prepared statement.

Comment: Tried this and it appears to be bringing out the correct value now (didn't realise before it wasn't), however the repeat region is still broken :-(

Comment: Did not understand about repeat region.

Comment: The repeat region just echo's out each row into the table so I can see what is in the query results.

Answer (score 0):

Hello a probable cause that i can figure out is do while loop will run first time always whether the while condition is true or not so i would suggest you to use while loop

```
<?php while ($row_CartDetails = mysql_fetch_assoc($CartDetails)) { ?>
<tr>
    <td><?php echo $row_CartDetails['Fixture']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row_CartDetails['EventType']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row_CartDetails['SwimmerFName']; ?> <?php echo $row_CartDetails['SwimmerSName']; ?></td>
    <td>£<?php echo $row_CartDetails['EventCost']; ?></td>
</tr>
<?php } ?>
```

The above code will save the extra <tr></tr>